# Programa c++ em Qt feito em linux para executar no WIndows

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

Pessoal queria saber se há alguma forma e se houver qual, para basicamente criar um executável ,de um programa GUI feito no Qt, para Windows sendo que estou usando Linux.

Comment: cara voce pode usar o mono ou ate o propio gcc mesmo e so compilar

Comment: Compilei aqui pelo QtCreator gerou um executavel,mas so roda no linux como seria de esperar sendo que compilei no linux. O que eu queria era criar um .exe para windows no linux.

Comment: Isso não é muito simples, pois caso use bibliotecas externas você devera fazer o port tambem, agora se for projeto simples, pegue ele salve o projeto no QT do linux, depois abra o projeto no QT no Windows e compile ele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe um projeto de código aberto chamado [**MXE**](http://mxe.cc/), *Minimalist/MinGW cross enviroment*. Ele parte do código fonte de várias bibliotecas e produz versões próprias para compilação para Windows, no Linux. O uso é bem simples, faça:

```
git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe
cd mxe
make qt5
```

Isso vai demorar algum tempo, mas só precisa ser feito uma vez. Depois vá até uma pasta vazia onde queira produzir o projeto compilado para Windows, rode o seguinte:

```
/pasta-onde-esta-o-mxe/usr/i686-w64-mingw32.static/qt5/bin/qmake pasta-do-seu-projeto-qt
```

Isso vai produzir um `Makefile` já configurado para o mxe. Agora extenda a sua `PATH` para conter o caminho do compilador do MXE, e rode o `make`

```
PATH=$PATH:/pasta-onde-esta-o-mxe/usr/bin
make
```

O resultado será um arquivo `.exe`. Pode até executar ele com o `wine`!

Answer (score 1):

Isso já é feito para outras plataformas e se chama **compilação cruzada** (*cross-compiling*). É como aplicativos desenvolvidos no Windows e no Linux são compilados para o Android. Eu realmente nunca vi ninguém fazendo *cross-compiling* Linux -> Windows, mas pode ser perfeitamente possível – só que você vai ter procurar saber como configurar isso. Você pode começar procurando *cross-compiling from Linux to Windows* e ver se algo te ajuda.

(Sei que é uma resposta meio fraca, mas não deu pra escrever isso tudo como um comentário só)